# loading external script source during on-click only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

> The code below always load script src when page load.

.

I have a website that clicks is on the right side(as menu item) then it loads page on the right side(content), but 1 page only.

.

How to load external script src during at onclick only?

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://xdomain.com/xout.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<a href="#xrefer"> <img id="idxclick" src="images/ximage.jpg" /></a>

<script>  
var handler = xout.xsetup({
    key: 'sd_FlP9fKY7TvINq4bWachJQ35P',
    image: '/images/xout.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
    //
    //
    }
});

$('#idxclick').on('click', function(e) {  
    handler.open({
    name: 'Hardware',
    description: 'Software',
    amount: '50.00'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I did what your code > here > but same thing happen >

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- script src="https://xdomain.com/xout.js"></script> REMOVED -->
</head>


<body>
<a href="#xrefer"> <img id="idxclick" src="images/ximage.jpg" /></a>

<script>  
$.getScript('https://xdomain.com/xout.js', function () {
// do some stuff after script is loaded

var handler = xout.xsetup({
    key: 'sd_FlP9fKY7TvINq4bWachJQ35P',
    image: '/images/xout.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
    //
    //
    }
});

$('#idxclick').on('click', function(e) {  
    handler.open({
    name: 'Hardware',
    description: 'Software',
    amount: '50.00'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});

});  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

.

> Your answer was correct!, thank you!, and this is much Better and Faster!  Prevent Double Click included.

.

```
    <html>

<head>
</head>


<body>
<a href="#xrefer"> <img id="idxclick" src="images/ximage.jpg" onmouseover="$.getScript('https://xdomain.com/xout.js')" /></a>

<script>  
    $('#idxclick').on('mouseout', function() {x=0})
    var x=0;
    $('#idxclick').on('click', function(e) { 
    if (x==0) {
    x=1;
var handler = xout.xsetup({
    key: 'sd_FlP9fKY7TvINq4bWachJQ35P',
    image: '/images/xout.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
    //
    //
    }
});


    handler.open({
    name: 'Hardware',
    description: 'Software',
    amount: '50.00'
    });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load a script with `$.getScript()` inside of your click event handler.

```
$('#idxclick').on('click', function(e) {
    $.getScript('https://xdomain.com/xout.js', function () {
        var handler = xout.xsetup({
                key: 'sd_FlP9fKY7TvINq4bWachJQ35P',
                image: '/images/xout.png',
                locale: 'auto',
                token: function(token) {
                    //
                    //
                };
        handler.open({
            name: 'Hardware',
            description: 'Software',
            amount: '50.00'
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I already tried that, does not work, can you please make a whole body page(sample of your code) with the above sample, thanks.  I mean you properly paste that where are in the code?

Comment: You need to place it **inside the event handler**. I added a complete code example in my answer to make it more clear.